# How to reliably get the filename without the suffix in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, filenames

Whats the reliable way on getting the filename of a file by removing suffix in javascript?

I have a file let's say :

http://example.com/uploads/images/a51dd42_thumb.jpg and http://example.com/uploads/images/a51dd42_s.jpg

Now i want to get the string http://example.com/uploads/images/a51dd42.jpg

replace() function is not what i want since images filename could have many different types of suffixes

Maybe regex is the best for this?

If yes, whats the reliable code for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it always have the `_` in there? So you want to get rid of what is inbetween the `_` and the `.` including the `_` istelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` function probably *is* what you want, and it can accept a regular expression as the search pattern:

```
url = url.replace(/_[^\/]+(\.[^\/]*)$/, "$1");
```

What that expression does: [Example on Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tI8gO8/1)

- Looks for an `_` that isn't followed by any slashes (so we're only looking at the final segment in the path).
- Allows any number of non-slash characters after the `_`.
- Stops matching those at the last `.` it finds followed by zero or more characters (I'm assuming these always have an extension on them); captures the `.` and the characters after it (e.g., the extension).
- Replaces the overall match with just the `.` and extension following it. (The `$1` in the replace string is special, it means "use the value of the first capture group.)

If your paths may or may not have an extension on them, just add a `?` near the end of the regex, just before the `$`: `/_[^\/]+(\.[^\/]*)?$/` (that makes everything in the capture group optional).

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/peqori/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: monospace;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    test("http://example.com/uploads/images/a51dd42_thumb.jpg");
    test("http://example.com/uploads/images/a51dd42_s.jpg");

    function test(url) {
      display("Before: " + url);
      url = url.replace(/_[^\/]+(\.[^\/]*)$/, "$1");
      display("After: " + url);
    }

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what i need so im marking the answer as check. :)
Just curious, what if i have two underscores like a51dd42_profile_thumb.jpg? i tested it in my local script but it replaces both _profile and _thumb

Comment: @MarkBonnieVestil: If you want that to end up being `a51dd42_profile.jpg`, we do the same thing we did to avoid matching within an earlier segment of the path: Exclude the `_` from the possible characters that can follow it (in both places, probably). So we end up with: `/_[^\/_]+(\.[^\/_]*)$/` (or `/_[^\/_]+(\.[^\/_]*)?$/` if the extension is optional). - http://jsbin.com/peqori/2 (That regex looks a bit angry, doesn't it? ;-D)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var s = 'http://example.com/uploads/images/a51dd42_thumb.jpg';
var r = s.replace(/^(.+?)_[^.]+(\.[^\/.]+)$/i, '$1$2');
//=> http://example.com/uploads/images/a51dd42.jpg
```

Comment: thanks. your code seems to be dependent in a extension like jpg.
Is there a better way where it will adapt to any type of extension?

Answer (score -1):

Split it easy

```
var start = Filename.split('_')[0], 
file = Filename.split('_')[1],
end = file.split('.')[1];
console.log(start + '.' + end);
```

.