# How to remove or change .html extension in my url using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html page url is **www.example.com/training/product.html.** I want to change my url like to **www.example.com/training/product.** Is it possible using javascript or Jquery? How?

Comment: Seems like something you should be handling server side.

Comment: you can try changing `window.location.href`, but after changing it might not work, this should be on server side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478485/jquery-change-the-url-address-without-redirecting

Answer (score 7):

Sorry I can not comment due to Reputation-Restriction.

The right solution is not yet in the comments.

```
window.history.replaceState()
```

does the job.

I would do:

```
var link = 'www.example.com/training/product.html';
link.split('.html')[0];
window.history.replaceState( null, null, link );
```

For a more respected solution go to [How to reliably get the filename without the suffix in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351184/how-to-reliably-get-the-filename-without-the-suffix-in-javascript)

## Link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState().C2.A0method

Comment: No need to make this a comment, this is the correct answer (with a documentation link even), plus now you're only 1 pt away from the comment priv. For browser compatibility (IE mainly has issues with this solution) there's also a solution which uses the hash (`#`) at the end of the URL to manipulate the text.

Comment: but now we can't reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using MVC. This can not be done by Javascript. This needs to be done on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Using `javascript` you can achieve this like:

```
var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
if (a.indexOf('html') > -1) { //Check of html String in URL.
   url = url.substring(0, newURL.lastIndexOf("."));
}
```

If you are looking at Server level changes, Below are the rules for .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .html requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.html([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .html file for extensionless html urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.html[L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Jquery :-

```
var url = "www.example.com/training/product.html";
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("."));
```